# Leetcode:Binary Tree Inorder Traversal.problem:Memory Limited exceeded

Tags: binary-tree, memory-limit

The following code performs a binarytree inorder traversal.  When I execute it in Leetcode, I receive a `Run Status Code: Memory Limit Exceeded`.  Could someone explain what is causing this error?

```
   vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {

    vector<int> res;
    if(root==NULL)
        return res;
    stack<TreeNode*> st;
    st.push(root);
    while(st.empty()==0){
        TreeNode* cur=st.top();
        st.pop();
        if(cur->right!=NULL)//right childtree is not NULL,push
            st.push(cur->right);
        if(cur->left!=NULL){//left childtree is not NULL,push
            st.push(cur);
            st.push(cur->left);
        }
        else       //if left child tree is NULL,store the value
            res.push_back(cur->val);

    }

    //inorder(root,res);
    return res;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your input? Where is the rest of your program? Try putting together a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only stores a value into the result stack if the left child node is a null.

However, for your example, node 2 left child node is never set to a null and hence it is never inserted into the result stack but it is in the st stack. If you print out your output, you can observe that 3 is inserted in a loop, hence causing a memory issue.

A possible strategy to keep track of the ancestor:

- Check for trivial case.
- Prepare a stack to keep the ancestors, and one to keep the result.
- While the stack is non-empty or if the root is not null

  - if the root is not null:

    - insert the root onto the ancestor stack.
    - update the root to be the left child of the root, possibly to be null.
  - if the root is null (meaning dead end from the left)

    - visit the stack, pop the top element to be the root.
    - add the root to the result stack
    - assign the right child of the root to be the root, possibly to be a null.